# Why ADO in Delphi can not access the INFORMATION_SCHEMA of SqlCe?

Tags: delphi, schema

I just want to check the if the table exists, then I create a query to access the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, with the code follow, but it's not work! Get an error of "Object is already opened".

```
procedure TForm2.Button11Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOConnection1.Close;
  ADOConnection1.ConnectionString:=
    'Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;'
      + 'Data Source=' + SdfFileName + ';';
  ADOConnection1.Open;

  ADOQuery1.Close;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:= 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES';
  ADOQuery1.Open;

  if not ADOQuery1.IsEmpty then
      ShowMessage(ADOQuery1.Fields[0].AsString);
end;
```

But, using the way of "COM", it's work fine! The code like this:

```
var
  Conn, Cmd, RS: OleVariant;
begin
  Conn:= CreateOleObject('ADODB.Connection');
  Cmd:= CreateOleObject('ADODB.Command');
  Conn.Open('Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;'
      + 'Data Source=' + SdfFileName + ';');
  Cmd.ActiveConnection:= Conn;
  Cmd.CommandText:= 'SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES';
  RS:= Cmd.Execute;
  if not RS.Eof then
    ShowMessage(RS.Fields[0].Value);
end;
```

WHY? The ADO wraped in Delphi is incomplete?

Comment: For getting table names you can use [`GetTableNames`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOConnection.GetTableNames) method.

Comment: Have you set `ADOQuery1.Connection := ADOConnection1`? @TLama +1. OP better use `TADOConnection.OpenSchema` (which is what `GetTableNames` does) than query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` directly.

Comment: GetTableNames is Delphi function? And, How to use TADOConnection.OpenSchema? The parameters is so hard to supply.

Comment: *Read* the doc @TLama gave you. its a method of `TADOConnection`. simply use `ADOConnection1.GetTableNames`. you can look the source (ADODB) to see how `OpenSchema` is used.

Comment: The source of GetTableNames method is clearly presents the usage of OpenSchema. I got it. Thanks all!